# Error in flutter update on Mac

Tags: runtime-error

[Error in flutter update on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01pk2.png) # # Error in flutter update on Mac ##

When trying to update Flutter using the "sudo flutter upgrade" command.

It has been updated correctly without errors, however when trying to run the following error occurs:

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 0d119a285fb3acee)

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

Since it is not a community response, I decided to delete Flutter and install again. To my surprise entering the official Flutter website, I saw that I had a MacOs hotfix and believe that this is what caused this problem on my machine.

Anyway the problem was solved in a very simple way. I deleted the old Flutter folder (Cmd + Del direct in the folder) I downloaded Flutter from the official website with the Hotfix unzipped in the same place as the previously deleted folder, and that problem solved.